# Avoid deadlock when the order of acquisition of locks is not guaranteed

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, deadlock

Suppose that I have the following class:

```
public class IntBagWithLock
{
    private readonly lockObject = new object();
    private bool assigned = false;
    private int data1;
    private int data2;

    public int? Data1
    {
        get { lock (lockObject) { return assigned ? data1 : (int?)null; } }
    }
    public int? Data2
    {
        get { lock (lockObject) { return assigned ? data2 : (int?)null; } }
    }
    public bool Assigned { get { lock(lockObject) { return assigned; } }

    public bool TrySetData(int value1, int value2)
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            if (assigned) return false;

            data1 = value1;
            data2 = value2;
            assigned = true;
            return true;
        }
    }

    public bool IsEquivalentTo(IntBagWithLock other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(other, null)) return false;

        lock (lockObject)
        {
            if (!assigned) return false;
            lock (other.lockObject)
            {
                return other.assigned && other.data1 == data1 && other.data2 == data2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am worried about here is that, because of the way that `IsEquivalentTo` is implemented, I could be left with a deadlock condition, if a thread invoked `item1.IsEquivalentTo(item2)` and acquired `item1`'s lock, and another invoked `item2.IsEquivalentTo(item1)` and acquired `item2`.

What should I do to ensure, as much as possible, that such deadlocks cannot happen?

**UPDATE 2**: The code sample has been modified to be closer to what I actually have. I think that all answers are still valid.

Comment: something strikes me as not right with that; can you tell us your actual use case?

Comment: @MitchWheat: I have a class that holds two data fields (both fields are immutable values), an instance can transition from one state to another, and I would like to operate as much as possible on known states.

Comment: Can you make your `IntBagWithLock` to initialize only through constructor? so that you can get rid of lock

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Yes, Immutability is generally my go-to recipe for thread safety, but in this case I am pretty sure that I want the data to be modified after instantiation.

Comment: You have immutable fields that can be changed? I'm not familiar with that particular definition of immutability.

Comment: @JimMischel: No, I mean that I usually make a given type thread safe by making it immutable, and that here I apply a different strategy because I need to.

Comment: Your comment above is misleading: "I have a class that holds two data fields (both fields are immutable values)."

Comment: @JimMischel: I should have phrased it with "both field values reference immutable objects or values", or something to that effect. (The main thing was to say that the only change that was significant were changes to the field). And the comment is outdated anyway after the second edit.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you give an unique ID to every object, and then lock from lower id to higher id:

```
public class BagWithLock
{
    // The first Id generated will be 1. If you want it to be 0, put
    // here -1 .
    private static int masterId = 0; 

    private readonly object locker = new object();

    private readonly int id = Interlocked.Increment(ref masterId);

    public static void Lock(BagWithLock bwl1, BagWithLock bwl2, Action action)
    {
        if (bwl1.id == bwl2.id)
        {
            // same object case
            lock (bwl1.locker)
            {
                action();
            }
        }
        else if (bwl1.id < bwl2.id)
        {
            lock (bwl1.locker)
            {
                lock (bwl2.locker)
                {
                    action();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lock (bwl2.locker)
            {
                lock (bwl1.locker)
                {
                    action();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You use it like:

```
bool equals;

BagWithLock(bag1, bag2, () => {
    equals = bag1.SequenceEquals(bag2);
});
```

so you pass an `Action` containing what you want to do inside the `lock`s.

The `Interlocked.Increment` on a `static masterId` guarantees an unique `id` to each class. Note that there *will* be problem if you create more than 4 billion instances of this class. If you need to do it, use `long`.

Comment: even if it wraps around you can still order; the chances of comparing two *equal* numbers is *incredibly* small (but at the same time: real)

Comment: @MarcGravell The classical bugs that you could search for days without finding it :-) At least I would put a check like: `if (bwl1.id == bwl2.id) { if (!object.ReferenceEquals) { throw Exception("Equal ID!"); }`

Answer (score 1):

i donno why you lock every time you do get or equal, but you can do:

```
public bool IsEquivalentTo(BagWithLock other)
{
    object myData;
    object otherData;
    lock (lockObject)
        myData = data;

    lock (other.lockObject)
        otherData = other.data;

    return object.Equals(myData, otherData);
}
```

that way the items won't change while they are compared.

in general, this kind of locks has some drawbacks, and i think that i would have done a general static `lockObject` so you could only has on object at a time in a method that could be a race condition

---

**UPDATE**
according to your update i'll say you should use:

```
private static readonly object equalLock = new object();

public bool IsEquivalentTo(IntBagWithLock other)
{
    lock(equalLock){
       if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
       if (ReferenceEquals(other, null)) return false;
         if (!assigned) return false;
           return other.assigned && other.data1 == data1 && other.data2 == data2;
   }
}
```

Comment: You should copy the object (assuming it's at all possible), not the reference to it. Otherwise, it won't prevent the objects being modified during the comparison.

Comment: The objects that I put in as data are immutable. (They are even built-in value types, but who cares).

Comment: @JeanHominal because i can take that object using the get, hold it, and change it whenever i want without the locks to take stopping me

Comment: @NoIdeaForName: Yes, I know why it is important to know that the objects are immutable. The "who cares" bit was about them being built-in value types.

Comment: @JeanHominal in that case a single lock of a mutex or a bunch of other ways will work perfectly, and you should lose the lock in the getter

Comment: @NoIdeaForName: Yes, that makes me think that I have simplified the sample code too much - I actually check the other data field in the getter and the setter. I will post another question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35839/discussion-between-jean-hominal-and-no-idea-for-name)

Comment: I have updated the question so as to better explain why I want to lock.

Comment: @JeanHominal edited my answer, but it's the same as i told you. it'll work fine

Comment: @NoIdeaForName: Wait, should I use the shared lock in the other methods of the class?

Comment: @JeanHominal not always, and it depends. for example, if you are to tell me you are doing 10000 compares in a second, i'd say not to use share lock, but to use GetHashCode and lock the object by the lower to higher number, so u get uniform behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Since OP mentioned `data` is `Immutable`, I think no need of locks at all here, `volatile' should do the trick.

```
public class BagWithLock
{
    private volatile object data;
    public object Data
    {
        get { lock return data; }
        set { data = value;  }
    }
    public bool IsEquivalentTo(BagWithLock other)
    {
        return object.Equals(data, other.data);
    }
}
```

This should be threadsafe. if am wrong pls correct me.

Comment: I have updated the question so as to better explain why I want to lock - that is, I have a bit of a more complex logic inside of the getter, that checks another field.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the more costly, `WaitHandle`-derived locking objects (such as [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx)), and use `WaitHandle.WaitAll()` when you want several locks at once?

Comment: Using `WaitHandle.WaitAll` to acquire multiple locks can lead to deadlock. It's possible for two threads to wait on the same set of locks. Each thread gets one of the locks and keeps waiting on the other . . . It gets messy quick.

Comment: I thought WaitAll (and the underlying Win32 function, WaitForMultipleObjects) was specifically capable of handling this case by "atomically" acquiring or releasing all locks, like `semop` in *n*x...

Comment: You're right. [WaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687028(v=vs.85).aspx) will wait for the mutex to be available, but won't acquire it until they're all available. My mistake.